# How to do this without lambda?

Tags: vb.net, lambda, continuewith

```
Public Shared Async Function getMarketDetailFromAllExchangesAsync() As Task
    Dim taskList = New List(Of Task)
    Dim starttime = jsonHelper.currentTimeStamp
    LogEvents("Start Getting Market Detail of All")
    For Each account In uniqueAccounts().Values
        Dim newtask = account.getMarketInfoAsync().ContinueWith(Sub() account.LogFinishTask("GetMarketDetail", starttime))
        taskList.Add(newtask)
        'newtask.ContinueWith(Sub() LogEvents(account.ToString))
    Next
    Await Task.WhenAll(taskList.ToArray)
    Dim b = 1
End Function
```

Is there a way to do .ContinueWith(Sub() account.LogFinishTask("GetMarketDetail", starttime)) with addressOf instead?

How?

Comment: Not if your method requires more than one parameter (and creating another method is not an option). But why do you even want to get rid of the lambda?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AddressOf with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143385/addressof-with-parameter)

Comment: You can define an Action somewhere else. Which is usually implemented with a Lambda :)

Comment: Kindly, try to choose better/meaningful titles for [your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55883154/4934172) :)

Comment: I think that one solve my problem. However, this question should stay. It's more clear. The other one is for handler.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a method which satisfies any of existed `ContinueWith` overloads.
In your particular case it should satisfy a signature of `Action(Of Task)`.

But because in `ConitnuesWith` you are using `account` instance, you will not be able to use `AddressOf` with method of the class where loop is executed.

As workaround you can create required method in class of `account`

```
Public Class Account
    Public Sub LogFinishedMarketDetail(task As Task)
        Dim starttime = jsonHelper.currentTimeStamp
        Me.LogFinishTask("GetMarketDetail, starttime")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Usage

```
For Each account In uniqueAccounts().Values
    Dim newtask = 
        account.getMarketInfoAsync().ContinueWith(AddressOf account.LogFinishedMarketDetail)
    taskList.Add(newtask)
Next
```

Suggestion - set `Option Strict` to `On` - will saves developer time by displaying possibly errors during compile time, instead of run-time.

Comment: I want to pass on more parameters than just the task. In fact, the task is not needed at all.

Comment: @user4951, that was my point, if you want to use a method which has different signature then lambdas accepted by `ContinueWith`, you should wrap your method with another which will have accepted signature.

Comment: `Option Strict On` will make your life much easier, because it will point you into possible type/signature problems much early and saves your time. For example with `Option String On` your code will not compile, because there are no `ContinueWith` overload which accepts `Action` as an argument